# Enable depreciations with phpunit bridge

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, simple-phpunit

I want upgrading my symfony 2.8, I would like to have the list of deprecations for my project. so I installed phpunit-bridge to run my unit tests.
However, phpunit does not return any deprecation information to me. The documentation does not specify a parameter to enable its notifications. Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.2.1",
    "khepin/yaml-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "gregwar/image-bundle": "dev-master",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3",
    "misd/phone-number-bundle": "^1.1",
    "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle": "^1.0",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
    "gesdinet/jwt-refresh-token-bundle": "^0.2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.2",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "evence/soft-deleteable-extension-bundle": "^1.3",
    "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "^2.0",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
    "twig/twig": "2.6.*",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "5.1.7"
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
    }
],
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0"
},
```

this is my config file for phpunit

```
<php>
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
    <!--
        <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
    -->
    <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="strict" />
</php>

<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
        <directory>../src/test/NotifBundle</directory>
        <directory>../src/Tests/Controller/ContractRESTControllerTest.php</directory>
        <directory>../src/test/ContractBundle/Tests</directory>

    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: Why do you use a Symfony 5.1 component on a 2.8 application? Also, how is this problem related to Composer itself?

Comment: ok i didn't know that the phpunit/bridge version was related to the symfony one.

Comment: And why did you choose a random outdated version then? Even the 5.1 release has a later version, besides 5.1 being pretty outdated

Comment: because I don't have the system requirements for newer versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add the listener that captures the deprecation messages and later on displays them to your `phpunit.xml`, for example through

```xml
<listeners>
    <listener class="Symfony\Bridge\PhpUnit\SymfonyTestsListener" />
</listeners>
```

Source: [Installation steps from the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/phpunit_bridge.html#installation)

Comment: thank you i will try with this configuration